# How do I update a node (book or Page) before saving it without touching the module code in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, module, save, drupal-alter, drupal-node-hook

I would like to set some values in the node before actually writing the data to the DB. I already have it working by modifying book_nodeapi but I would like to do it from outside the code, some _alter option that allows me to leave the module code untouched would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you need, [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module can be very useful in such tasks.
All you need to do is to create a condition according to the content type you want, and to have an action that sets the value.
Setting the value can be done using static values, [Token](http://drupal.org/project/Token) values, or even PHP code.

[Here](http://nodeone.se/blogg/johan-falk/nodeone-talks-drupal-rules-%E2%80%93-the-basics) is a screencast with Rules basics.

Comment: +1 - this is a somewhat less flexible way compared to ceejayoz suggestion of using `hook_nodeapi`, but might be enough for your needs and does not require custom code in a custom module.

Comment: Well, true.
I read "I would like to do it from outside the code" and thought you really don't want to code...

Answer (score 2):

You can make a custom module and implement [`hook_nodeapi`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi/6) (`mymodule_nodeapi`) in it just as the book module does. Every active module gets a chance to hook into nodeapi for all nodes.

Comment: +1 - this is the most flexible way to do this - you'd need to make your changes on the `presave` operation (the insert/update operations will be triggered only *after* the node has been saved to the database)